# Data Correlation for computing software metrics

Tags: data-visualization, computational-statistics, software

I have the below sets of data per application, you can call them as software metrics. These metrics vary depending on the size of an application.

```
Bugs
CodeSmells
Vulnerability
```

The size of the application is determined by LOC (Lines of code), how can i showcase the complexity of each app relative to the lines of code if i visualize each of these parameters.

> Example

```
           Bugs   LOC
SweetApp   10     10000
SourApp    120    5660000
SaltyApp   55     1500
```

How do i visualize Bugs per app in relation to the LOC, because LOC determines their complexity a higher number in bugs doesn't necessarily be bad considering a higher number in LOC.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what kind of help you're requesting?  A recommendation for a particular type of chart perhaps?  If so, are you weighing certain options already?

Comment: That's right, i am looking for some type of a chart where i can visualize the application complexity. I have a bar chart for each of these parameters and they show how many bugs/codesmells per app

However i also need to show how complex the app is using LOC in the same chart.

Comment: The magnitude of LOC has such a large range that you may need to take the log of it...Have you tried a stacked bar chart?  Or maybe a "circle packing" chart as at https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/?s=packing